# Модальное окно открывается 2 раза

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Необходимо выполнить следующую задачу: по нажатию на кнопку открыть модальное окно (bootstrap) и после его закрытия отправить форму. Все вроде бы легко, но увы, мой код как то не по плану работает

Открытие модального окна:

```
$('#valid_button').click(function (){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ($('.field-payments-mpurse').hasClass('has-success') && $('.field-payments-summ').hasClass('has-success'))
        {
            $('#capcha_modal').modal('show');
        }
    }, 400);
});
```

Отправка формы после закрытия:

```
$('#capcha_modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#form_pay').submit();
});
```

Код окна:

```
<form id="form_pay" action="payments/create" method="post">
<div id="capcha_modal" class="fade modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                Капча
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group field-payments-recaptcha">
                    <label class="control-label" for="payments-recaptcha"></label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="payments-recaptcha" name="Payments[reCaptcha]">
                    <div class="help-block"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" id="valid_button" class="btn btn-success">Вывести</button>
</div>
```

Все элементарно просто, но по какой то причине окно открывается 2-ой раз после закрытия и отправка формы происходит только после 2-го закрытия, ничто иное как сверхъестественные силы, а вы как считаете?

Comment: Почему на открытие модального окна стоит `setTimeout`?

Comment: Необходима задержка перед открытием

Comment: Ок. Прикрепите html код модалки, чтобы понятнее было как ваш скрипт работает.

Comment: Добавил html код

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить этот обработчик вместо вашего:

```
$('#capcha_modal').on('click', '.close', function (e) {
    $('#form_pay').submit();
});
```

P.S. Также закройте тег `<form>` если она у вас и в рабочей версии не закрыта.

**UPD**

Если используете Bootstrap 3, то обработчик закрытия модалки выглядит следующим образом:

```
$('#capcha_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

[Документация](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events), [ответ на аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363802/bind-a-function-to-twitter-bootstrap-modal-close)

Comment: `$('#capcha_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#form_pay').submit();
    })`
Именно так написано в документации бутстрапа и оно работает, но не понятно почему второй раз открывается окно после закрытия

Comment: @M.Texh Наверно потому, что у вас в коде написано `hide.bs.modal`.

Comment: Исправил, нет изменений

Comment: @M.Texh Версия Bootstrap какая?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 селектор срабатывает

Comment: Тогда возможно проблема с `setTimeout`. Уберите его и попробуйте снова.

Comment: Выяснил, что дело в кнопке #valid_button, она вызывается 2-й раз после закрытия окна, но опять же не понятно почему

Comment: Без setTimeout так же